# Is there a way to avoid waking up the cdrom when running explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, compact-disc

When I type Win+E to run Explorer, it takes several seconds to appear. The main reason seems to be because the cdrom wakes up. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: You need to install a 1 megawatt motor or higher in the CD drive so it can spin up in a few milliseconds </sarc>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could unassign the drive letter from it through `diskmgmt.msc` or `mountvol` (and then assign to `C:\Media\CD-ROM`, for example).

Answer (score 6):

It's a true annoyance, easiest way is to not leave a CD in it, it shouldn't spin up if it is empty.